# problem performing recursive call in quick sort assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, x86-64, quicksort

I'm having a problem implementing quicksort in assembly, when I'm trying to perform the second recursive call to qsort(arr,pi+1,high) I don't know why, but it exits the recursion too early.

I've tried using the stack and writing helper functions, but everything I've tied created new problems. When debbuging, I see that I exit the function when %ebx = 4 and %ecx = 5 and the array is almost sorted array ={10,30,40,50,70,90,80} - I need only to perform the last swap when %ebx = 5 and %ecx = 6, but it exits before, and I don't understand why it won't go back to when %ecx was 6.

I thought perhaps the problem is when I'm making the comparisons between high and low, but If I change those, I'm having different problems (it exists too early the first recursive call). perhaps anyone has an idea what's wrong with my code?

here's my code:

```
.data
array: .int 10, 80, 30, 90, 40, 50, 70
size: .int 7

.text
.global main
main:
    movl $0, %ebx       # low index
    movl (size), %ecx   # high index
    dec %ecx            # ecx = size -1
qsort:
    cmp %ecx, %ebx # high > low
    jge end

    movsx %ecx, %r13    # push high
    movsx %ebx, %r12    # push low    
    call partition # rax now is the pivot

    movq %r12, %rbx # pop low
    movl %eax, %ecx # prepare new high = pi
    subl $1, %ecx # high = pi-1
    call qsort # qsort(arr,low,pi-1)

    movl %eax,%ebx # push new low = pi+1
    inc %ebx
    call qsort # qsort(arr,pi+1,high) 

    ret

partition:
    movq %r12, %rax # get low
    movq %r13, %rbx # get high
    movl %eax, %ecx # j = low
    subl $1, %eax # i = low-1
    movl array(,%ebx,4), %edx # pivot = array[high]


    swap_loop:
    cmp %ebx, %ecx # high > j
    jge swap_greater
    movl array(,%ecx,4), %esi # esi = array[j]
    cmp %edx, %esi # pivot > array[j] ?
    jge loops # jmp if array[j] > pivot
    inc %eax # i++

    # swap 
    movsx %esi, %rsi
    pushq %rsi
    movl array(,%eax,4), %edi # edi = array[i]
    movl %edi, array(,%ecx,4) # array[j]=array[i]
    pop %rsi
    movl %esi, array(,%eax,4) # array[i]= previous array[j]

    loops:
    inc %ecx # j++
    jmp swap_loop

    swap_greater:
    inc %eax
    movsx %edx, %rdx
    pushq %rdx
    movl array(,%eax,4), %edi # edi = array[i+1]
    movl %edi, array(,%ebx,4) # array[high]=array[i+1]
    pop %rdx
    movl %edx, array(,%eax,4) # array[i+1]= previous array[high]
    dec %eax

    end_p:
    inc %eax
    ret

    end:
    inc %ecx
    movsx %ecx, %r13 # update high
    ret
```

---

edit: as Peter Cordes has pointed out - I need to work with the stack in order to retrieve the parameters when I go back from the recursive calls. after re-writing my code using the stack, I have a new problem, I always pop out the same thing on the second recursive call. I don't understand why it doesn't do the "recursive folding" like in C, when I look at the stack there's something weird, since I'm not seeing the values as I excpect ( I excpect to see layers or rax-high-low-rax-high-low...etc) but instead there are those numbers:

```css
native process 42032 In: second_rec                                                                          L??   PC: 0x4005ea 
0x7fffffffdeb0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000001
0x7fffffffdec0: 0x0000000000000002      0x00000000004005ef
0x7fffffffded0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000002
0x7fffffffdee0: 0x0000000000000001      0x00000000004005df
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000001
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x0000000000000002      0x00000000004005df
0x7fffffffdf10: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000002
0x7fffffffdf20: 0x0000000000000003      0x00000000004005df
0x7fffffffdf30: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000003
0x7fffffffdf40: 0x0000000000000004      0x00007ffff7a05b97
0x7fffffffdf50: 0x0000000000000001      0x00007fffffffe028
0x7fffffffdf60: 0x0000000100008000      0x00000000004005a7
```

perhaps I'm not pushing\popping in the right timing, but from what I've understood, I'm pushing parameters before call, and popping them when I return from the call... does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong? the new code:

```css
.data
array: .int 10, 80, 30, 90, 40, 50, 70
size: .int 7

.text
.global main
main:
    movl $0, %ebx       # low index
    movl (size), %ecx   # high index
    dec %ecx            # ecx = size -1
qsort:
    cmp %ecx, %ebx # high > low
    jge end
    movsx %ecx, %rcx    # prepare high
    movsx %ebx, %rbx    # prepare low    
    pushq %rcx          # push high
    pushq %rbx          # push low
    call partition # rax now is the pivot
    popq %rbx # pop low
    popq %rcx # pop high
    movsx %eax, %rax
    pushq %rax          # push pivot
    movl %eax, %ecx # prepare new high = pi
    subl $1, %ecx # pi-=1
    movsx %ecx, %rcx
    pushq %rcx          # push high
    pushq %rbx          # push low
    call qsort # qsort(arr,low,pi-1)
second_rec:  
    popq %rbx           # pop low
    popq %rcx           # pop high
    popq %rax           # pop pivot
    movl %eax, %ecx     # high = pi
    addl $1, %ecx       # high = pi+1
    pushq %rax          # push pivot
    pushq %rcx          # push high
    pushq %rbx          # push low
    call qsort # qsort(arr,pi+1,high)
    addq $24, %rsp 
    ret
    
partition:
    movq 8(%rsp), %rax           # get low
    movq 16(%rsp), %rbx          # get high
    movl %eax, %ecx # j = low
    subl $1, %eax # i = low-1
    movl array(,%ebx,4), %edx # pivot = array[high]
    
    
    swap_loop:
    cmp %ebx, %ecx # high > j
    jge swap_greater
    movl array(,%ecx,4), %esi # esi = array[j]
    cmp %edx, %esi # pivot > array[j] ?
    jge loops # jmp if array[j] > pivot
    inc %eax # i++
    
    # swap 
    movsx %esi, %rsi
    pushq %rsi
    movl array(,%eax,4), %edi # edi = array[i]
    movl %edi, array(,%ecx,4) # array[j]=array[i]
    pop %rsi
    movl %esi, array(,%eax,4) # array[i]= previous array[j]
    
    loops:
    inc %ecx # j++
    jmp swap_loop
    
    swap_greater:
    inc %eax
    movsx %edx, %rdx
    pushq %rdx
    movl array(,%eax,4), %edi # edi = array[i+1]
    movl %edi, array(,%ebx,4) # array[high]=array[i+1]
    pop %rdx
    movl %edx, array(,%eax,4) # array[i+1]= previous array[high]
    dec %eax
    
    end_p:
    inc %eax
    ret
    
    end:
    ret
```

Thank you very much everyone for your help!

Comment: "I've tried using the stack and writing helper functions, but everything I've tied created new problems." Bypassing the stack is not going to help solve your problems. More likely, it will break the whole idea of recursion.

Comment: I don't see your `qsort` function saving/restoring any registers, or saving anything on the stack.  How are its local variables going to get preserved across the child call that uses the same registers?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm saving them in r12 and r13 which are preserved on call, and I restore them in partition and in qsort also, after the recursive call

Comment: Yes, in the standard ABI, r12 and r13 are supposed to be call-preserved.  But that doesn't happen by magic; you have to make that happen yourself!  e.g. with `push %r12` on entry, `pop %r12` before ret.

Comment: @PeterCordes took me 3 days but I understood what you are talking about. thank you vary much for your guidance. it still doesn't work, now I have different problem, I understand what's the problem but this recursion thing gives me a headache and I can't understand what do I need to do in order to solve it. I've edited  my question, perhaps you have any idea how can I fix this problem?
thank you very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps looking at compiler-generated code for a simple recursive problem can help?  Compile with at most `gcc -O1` or `-Og` will get the compiler to use registers, but should stop it from optimizing recursion into loops.  I'd recommend reading [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38552509) and watching the linked video in general.

Comment: I've tried it, but I think I lack the knowledge to use it efficiently. I'll read what you've suggested and try to lean from this. thank you!

Comment: Also, just use normal code-formatting blocks like in fuz's edit.  Your code snippets aren't JavaScript that can run in a browser.  For some reason you went back to the wrong way.

Comment: In your stack dump, `0x00000000004005df` looks like a return address.  That's the right range for where a non-PIE Linux executable will have its `.text` section.  Remember that `call` pushes a return address for a later `ret` to pop back into RIP.